# What java data structure should I use to sort this data?

Tags: java, android, json, sorting, data-structures

I am using the `Facebook SDK` for `Android` to pull a list of a given user's friends. The problem is that the friends are sorted by `userid` (useless to the end-user). I need them sorted alphabetically.

Currently, I have the list in a `JSONArray`, and I'm wondering what sort of data structure I should put the names into in order to achieve optimal sorting. So we need to consider **insertion time, sort time, and fetch time**.

From reading other similar situations online, I am currently leaning towards a `TreeSet`, but that is just a hunch. What do you all think?

Comment: Try something.  If you think it's too slow try something else.  How many friends do you think you'll need to sort? Unless it's millions then I'd use whichever sort is simplest.

Comment: If you're only inserting the data once, then I'd try a TreeMap. However if you're doing a lot of inserting, then I'd use a HashMap as it will have better insert speed: O(1) vs O(n log n)

Comment: Why do you want a map to hold a list? Just use a list and Collections.sort() that is O(nlogn)

Comment: @aromero, I meant TreeSet. Sorry. The OP has been fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use `TreeSet`, but not for performance reasons. `TreeSet` implements `SortedSet` so you have you user list always sorted with right comparator given.
And `Set` also makes it easy to update: Just put all new Users into the set regardless they are already in or not. Sets do not contain duplicates.

I would not think a second about performance here since nobody will have such huge friendslists that it makes a difference.

Answer (score 2):

I would use [TreeMap](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html) or [HashMap](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) (or the set implementations for each TreeSet-HashSet). You'll need to either implement [Comparable](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) or use a [Comparator](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) for the sorting to work, though. Regarding speed, I don't think you'll face any considerable issues unless you are dealing with hugh amounts of data.